# Distribution of objects in equal size groups

Tags: java, sorting, grouping, distribution

Let there be a large set of objects, each providing a `getSize()` method that returns a number representing a "size" of some kind. This set is (or can be) sorted according to size.

For simplicity, also assume that:

- The group size is larger than the largest object size, so that each group contains at least one object
- There is no limitation to the total number of groups

Given the above, what would be an efficient way of distributing those objects into groups, so that the total size of all objects in a group is (approximately) the same to that of all other groups?

Obviously one can walk the set linearly and put an object into a group if it fits, or create another group and put it there if is does not, but this approach does not achieve equal size distribution.

The problem is independent of programming languages, but an example implementation in `Java` would also be interesting.

Comment: How about putting them all in a `TreeMap`? The key would be the result from the `getSize()` method and the values will be Lists containing the corresponding objects.

Comment: That would be a solution (and +1) if the "equal size" referred to each of the objects, instead of each of the groups. The question refers to the groups size. I have clarified it further. Thanks.

Comment: A rather hopeful / naive approach could be to iterate the sorted set from both sides, adding the front object into a group with the back object (though, if there are an odd number of objects, you'll have a group with only 1 object).

Comment: Clever! It may not be fully accurate, but it could give a good approximation.